How to understand Bott & Tu Prop. 9.5?
I am reading Bott & Tu's Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology. The book constructs a chain homotopy between the Čech-de Rham double complex and the de Rham complex.
However, I'm unclear about the explanation of the construction of $f$ (in the last paragraph of the graph). From my understanding: $f(\alpha)$ is actually a global form (an $n$-form on $M$), whose restriction on $U_i$ is given by the formula for $f(\alpha)$ in section 9.5. The $n$-forms on each $U_i$ are summed with coefficients $\pm 1$. However, it isn't stated that these are compactly supported $n$-forms, so they can't be extended to the whole $M$ by $0$, making it seem impossible to add them. What went wrong? What is the correct understanding?
